# connect local python script to remote spark master

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am using python 2.7 with spark standalone cluster.

When I start the master on the same machine running the python script. it works smoothly.

When I start the master on a remote machine, and try to start spark context on the local machine to access the remote spark master. nothing happens and i get a massage saying that the task did not get any resources.

When i access the master's UI. i see the job, but nothing happens with it, it's just there.

How do i access a remote spark master via a local python script?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
I read that in order to do this i need to run the cluster in cluster mode (not client mode), and I found that currently [standalone mode does not support this for python application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to do this i need to run the cluster in cluster mode (not client mode), and I found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) that currently standalone mode does not support this for python application.